# Specifying command line parameters in Process.start

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer, process.start

I am trying to write a windows application in C# where - the user selects an MSI file and an Instance Name and on clicking the 'Run Installer' button.......the MSI file will be invoked with the instance name as a parameter.

So basically the the command generated will look like:

```
msiexec  /i "E:\Local Profile\Desktop\BranchBankingConnectorSetup.msi" MSINEINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=:Instance1
```

The problem is.....after I run the installer for the first time and Instance 1 of the Branch Banking Connectors is installed.....if I try to run again with Instance 2  - the program still brings up  the Installer for Instance 1.

This is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p  = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "e:\\command.bat";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```

The file e:\command.bat contains the above mention command and this file is first updated with the selected instance number and then called.

Comment: I hope you're not using MSINETINSTANCE and that it's a typo in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a batch file
you can pass arguments within the StartInfo

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p  = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"; //You better provide a full path here
p.StatInfo.Arguments = " /i \"E:\\Local Profile\\Desktop\\BranchBankingConnectorSetup.msi\" MSINEINSTANCE=1 TRANSFORMS=:Instance1";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p.StatInfo.Arguments = "required arguments"
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem.

Comment: @BaummitAugen i am under the impression that OP wants to pass command line arguments to **command.bat**. In the batch file OP uses **%n** (n is a number) to fetch the parameters.